# Algorithms to reduce matrix bandwidth

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

I'm currently working on a variant of a non-convex low-rank matrix completion algorithm, whereby we take a uniform sample of entries in a (symmetric) matrix and look to complete said matrix. For various reasons, we're interested in trying to reduce the bandwidth of our matrix initialization for our algorithm, and our first idea was using the reverse Cuthill-McKee algorithm to do this (mostly just because it's pre-built in matlab). However, the output structure of the Cuthill-McKee algorithm provides a poor initialization for our algorithm.

I'm mostly just curious if there are other bandwidth reducing algorithms that people use regularly. I did a brief literature search and found some papers using neural networks to try and learn permutations to decrease the bandwidth, which looks interesting but is more work than I think is worth for this particular problem.

Comment: Do you actually need a banded matrix? What are the basic operations that you need to do with your matrix? Solve linear systems, find eigenvalues, find singular values, compute various factorizations? Yes, matrices that are banded and dense within the band can be processed efficiently, but such matrices are not common outside of a few select applications. Depending on what you need to do it is likely that treating the matrix as a general sparse matrix is more advantageous. If you add more information about your end goal then we might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm constructing a divide and conquer algorithm for a nearest-neighbors sampling model for a sensor localization problem (i.e., distances between points are revealed if they're within a set radius), then doing matrix completion for this incomplete Euclidean distance problem. For the way I'm doing this, I'm keeping info on the diagonal blocks while discarding information on the off-diagonals (speeds up the algorithm we're using). If more of the information is contained in the blocks, that's good for us. Random shuffling helps initialization post RCM, which I tried after posting yesterday.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you need a reordering that considers the actual values rather than the sparsity pattern of the matrix. There is in HSL library subroutines such as MC64 that will return a column perturbation that will maximize the sum/products of the elements on the main diagonal. After this initial permutation you can then apply symrcm. This is the best I can do without a more detailed description of your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into this.